# How to avoid antivirus affecting the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I start my emulator either it starts very late or does not start. I have to turn off
Real Time scanning of antivirus. How can I exclude emulator from being scanned or make it safe so that antivirus won't scan it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize Android Studio performance on Windows, exclude the following directories from real-time scanning by your antivirus software:

**Gradle cache:** `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle`

**Android Studio projects:** `%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`

**Android SDK:** `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK`

**Android Studio system files:** `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\<product><version>*`

If you're using Windows 10/11 default security app, here's a guide on how to add an exclusion: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26